# Can loading scripts/modules only within a listener function cause issues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

My Express application contains JS code snippets that are used under specific circumstances; to be precise, only when request from a certain site is coming.

In prectice, it'd look like this:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  switch (req.body.source) {
    case "/site1":
      var sitescr_a = require('sitesc_a');
      sitescr_a.DoStuff();
      break;

    case "/site2":
      var sitescr_b = require('sitesc_b');
      sitescr_b.DoStuff();
      break;
  };
}
```

Of course, it means that neither `sitescr_a.DoStuff()` nor `sitescr_b.DoStuff()` are available in other cases - which is my aim, because those are specific scripts -, but does it cause any other issues? Or is it a method considered safe?

Comment: Did you forget to to prefix the `sitescr_a` and `sitescr_b` definitions with a `var`? You may want to edit your post.

Comment: @Litty oh yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is *unusual* practice, it's perfectly acceptable to `require` inside of a function.

There's no requirement to do this at the top of a file, and variable scoping will work as you expect.

Comment: Consider that a personal opinion. I've never seen anyone do this -- that's all. (: